# Parse Android Crash Reporting Issue

Tags: android, parse-platform, crash-reports

I'm using Parse as a backend for my android app, I want to use Crash Reporting. but this is not working.

I'm using the last Parse SDK : `v1.10.3

I have a class where I initialize Parse :

```
public class Parse extends android.app.Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ParseCrashReporting.enable(this);
        com.parse.Parse.initialize(this, "KEY", "KEY");
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
        ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("main");
    }
}
```

and I'm adding this class to the Android manifest file so execute this class once and don't cause initializing parse crash.

```
 <application
        android:name=".Parse"
```

The crash reporting doesn't seem to work, I have no crashes appeared panel I made Parse test. but no crashes appeared.

I have some messages on my application log when I added :

```
 throw new RuntimeException("Test Exception!");
```

on my MainActivity.

Here is the log :

```
 E/CrashReporting: ParseCrashReporting caught a RuntimeException exception for com.example.yasser.version6. Building report.
10-17 22:06:19.408 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 E/CrashReporting: Handling exception for crash
10-17 22:06:19.408 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 E/CrashReporting: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.yasser.version6/com.example.yasser.version6.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Test Exception!
10-17 22:06:19.408 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 E/CrashReporting:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2411)
10-17 22:06:19.408 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 E/CrashReporting:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2474)
10-17 22:06:19.408 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 E/CrashReporting:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
10-17 22:06:19.408 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 E/CrashReporting:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1359)
10-17 22:06:19.408 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 E/CrashReporting:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-17 22:06:19.408 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 E/CrashReporting:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
10-17 22:06:19.408 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 E/CrashReporting:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
10-17 22:06:19.408 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 E/CrashReporting:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-17 22:06:19.408 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 E/CrashReporting:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-17 22:06:19.408 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 E/CrashReporting:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
10-17 22:06:19.408 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 E/CrashReporting:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
10-17 22:06:19.408 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 E/CrashReporting:  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Test Exception!
10-17 22:06:19.408 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 E/CrashReporting:     at com.example.yasser.version6.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:171)
10-17 22:06:19.408 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 E/CrashReporting:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5958)
10-17 22:06:19.408 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 E/CrashReporting:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
10-17 22:06:19.408 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 E/CrashReporting:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
10-17 22:06:19.408 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 E/CrashReporting:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2474) 
10-17 22:06:19.408 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 E/CrashReporting:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
10-17 22:06:19.408 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 E/CrashReporting:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1359) 
10-17 22:06:19.408 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 E/CrashReporting:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
10-17 22:06:19.408 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 E/CrashReporting:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155) 
10-17 22:06:19.408 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 E/CrashReporting:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696) 
10-17 22:06:19.408 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 E/CrashReporting:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
10-17 22:06:19.408 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 E/CrashReporting:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
10-17 22:06:19.408 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 E/CrashReporting:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028) 
10-17 22:06:19.408 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 E/CrashReporting:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823) 
10-17 22:06:19.408 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 D/CrashReporting: Generating report file for crash
10-17 22:06:19.488 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 I/System: exec(logcat -t 200 -v time @ com.parse.LogCatCollector.collectLogCat:87)
10-17 22:06:19.518 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 D/CrashReporting: Retrieving logcat output...
10-17 22:06:19.528 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 I/System: exec(logcat -b events -t 200 -v time @ com.parse.LogCatCollector.collectLogCat:87)
10-17 22:06:19.548 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 D/CrashReporting: Retrieving logcat output...
10-17 22:06:19.558 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 I/System: exec(logcat -b radio -t 200 -v time @ com.parse.LogCatCollector.collectLogCat:87)
10-17 22:06:19.579 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 D/CrashReporting: Retrieving logcat output...
10-17 22:06:19.649 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 W/Settings: Setting data_roaming_allowed has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Secure, returning read-only value.
10-17 22:06:19.649 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 W/Settings: Setting data_roaming_blocked has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Secure, returning read-only value.
10-17 22:06:19.649 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 W/Settings: Setting data_roaming_guard_allowed has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Secure, returning read-only value.
10-17 22:06:19.649 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 W/Settings: Setting data_roaming_guard_blocked has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Secure, returning read-only value.
10-17 22:06:19.689 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 W/Settings: Setting sms_roaming_guard_allowed has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Secure, returning read-only value.
10-17 22:06:19.689 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 W/Settings: Setting voice_roaming_allowed has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Secure, returning read-only value.
10-17 22:06:19.689 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 W/Settings: Setting voice_roaming_blocked has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Secure, returning read-only value.
10-17 22:06:19.689 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 W/Settings: Setting voice_roaming_guard_allowed has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Secure, returning read-only value.
10-17 22:06:19.689 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 W/Settings: Setting voice_roaming_guard_blocked has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Secure, returning read-only value.
10-17 22:06:19.689 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 W/Settings: Setting vzw_global_roaming_options has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Secure, returning read-only value.
10-17 22:06:19.749 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 W/Settings: Setting boot_lock has moved from android.provider.Settings.Secure to android.provider.Settings.Global.
10-17 22:06:19.749 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 W/Settings: Setting data_encryption has moved from android.provider.Settings.Secure to android.provider.Settings.Global.
10-17 22:06:19.769 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 W/Settings: Setting sd_encryption has moved from android.provider.Settings.Secure to android.provider.Settings.Global.
10-17 22:06:19.769 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 W/Settings: Setting tethering_blocked has moved from android.provider.Settings.Secure to android.provider.Settings.Global.
10-17 22:06:19.789 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 V/CrashReporting: About to start ReportSenderWorker from #handleException
10-17 22:06:19.799 1863-1943/com.example.yasser.version6 D/CrashReporting: #checkAndSendReports - start
10-17 22:06:19.799 1863-1943/com.example.yasser.version6 D/CrashReporting: Looking for error files in /data/data/com.example.yasser.version6/files/com.parse/cr/reports
10-17 22:06:19.799 1863-1943/com.example.yasser.version6 D/CrashReporting: Loading file 1445112379423-RuntimeException-1.stacktrace
10-17 22:06:19.809 1863-1943/com.example.yasser.version6 I/CrashReporting: Sending file 1445112379423-RuntimeException-1.stacktrace
10-17 22:06:19.809 1863-1943/com.example.yasser.version6 D/CrashReporting: Sending crash report to Parse...
10-17 22:06:19.809 1863-1943/com.example.yasser.version6 D/CrashReporting: #checkAndSendReports - finish
```

Manifest :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.yasser.version6" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.yasser.version6.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.yasser.version6.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:name=".Parse"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon"
            android:resource="@mipmap/ic_notiflogo" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <provider
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
            android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider1009675892446854"
            android:exported="true" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ActivitySignup"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_acitivity_signup"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".NewprofileActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_newprofile"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" >
>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".PublierActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_publier"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" >
>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".EditName"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_edit_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Mespublications"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_mespublications"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".EditPublication"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_edit_publication"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".EditText"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_edit_text"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AboutActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_about"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MyContacts_Activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_my_contacts_"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Verification_activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_verification_activity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Filtercontacts"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_filtercontacts" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LikesActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_likes" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".CropActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_crop" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Profile"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_profile"
            android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MyProfile" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Options"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_options"
            android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".CommentActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_comment"
            android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme" >
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".Notifications.CustomPushReceiver"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <!-- IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name. -->
                <category android:name="com.example.yasser.version6" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".Notif_Ativity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_notif__ativity"
            android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Try posting your entire manifest

Comment: Please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33218548/unhandled-exception-com-parse-parseexception-android-studio/33218795#33218795) link

Comment: try to add a log before ParseCrashReporting.enable(this); Log.e(TAG,"In application Class"); sometimes it happens the class is not loaded ( happened to me ) also give the full path of the class in manifest android:name="com.example.yasser.version6.Parse" (assumed the class is in that package ) this is to confirm that ur application class is loaded :)

Comment: Crash reporting is deprecated by Parse.

Answer (score 0):

Crash reporting is now deprecated and you will not be able to find it in the SDk.

See here: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android/issues/247

Answer (score -1):

As per your `CrashReporting: Retrieving logcat output.`

> 10-17 22:06:19.649 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 W/Settings: Setting data_roaming_allowed has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Secure, returning **read-only** value.
>
> 10-17 22:06:19.649 1863-1863/com.example.yasser.version6 W/Settings: Setting  data_roaming_blocked has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Secure, returning **read-only** value.

You need to `enable` **Client push** in Parse app **Setting**.
Go to Parse app console [here](https://www.parse.com/apps).
for more idea see below image.

[image]
 - And also just need to update your code like this

```
    public class Parse extends android.app.Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ParseCrashReporting.enable(this);
        com.parse.Parse.initialize(this, "KEY", "KEY");
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
        ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("main", new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
      Log.d("For Parse Push", "Success Push");
    } else {
      Log.e("For Parse Push", "Failed push", e);
      }
     }
    });
     }
}
```

Comment: How is crash reporting or those messages in the log output are relevant to User ACL permissions ???!

Comment: just you need to check [this](https://parse.com/questions/comparseparseexception-object-not-found-for-update-error-when-the-object-exists) to get more.

Comment: Not really. There is nothing relevant in that link regarding crash reporting feature. I do not know what you are talking about

Comment: Push notifications are working fine ! my issue is the crash reporting, so I don't see what the link with that ! Anyway I tried this ! still not working