# Unhandled exception: com.parse.parseException android studio

Tags: android, parse-platform

Here is my code:

```
 package com.alibdeir.database;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.parse.GetCallback;
    import com.parse.Parse;
    import com.parse.ParseObject;
    import com.parse.ParseQuery;
    import com.parse.SaveCallback;
    import com.parse.ParseException;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        TextView output;
        Button increase;
        int currentInt;



        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Parse.initialize(this, "QeaC0wiXsL9MyRbLaQ***********", "kDjoZVRu4OyWOGxPtPjh**************");
            output =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
            increase = (Button) findViewById(R.id.increase);
            ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("int");
            ParseObject o = query.get-("n6zA3CHxGx");
        }
        public void increase(View v) {

            currentInt = Integer.parseInt(output.getText().toString());
            output.setText(currentInt + 1 + "");
        }
    }
```

Notice:
 ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("int");
 ParseObject o = query.get("n6zA3CHxGx");

On hover of query.get("n6zA3CHxGx"); i have the error mentioned in the title.
I am trying to update an object that's in the parse cloud.
The object IS in the cloud.
Please help

Comment: please view [this](https://parse.com/questions/comparseparseexception-object-not-found-for-update-error-when-the-object-exists) thread

Answer (score 0):

1. Trying your code with handle exception using  `try { .. } catch` like this.

   ```
   try {
   Parse.initialize(this, "QeaC0wiXsL9MyRbLaQ***********", "kDjoZVRu4OyWOGxPtPjh**************");
       output =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
       increase = (Button) findViewById(R.id.increase);
       ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("int");
       ParseObject o = query.get-("n6zA3CHxGx");
   } catch (com.parse.ParseException e1) {
   e1.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```
2. As per [this](https://parse.com/questions/comparseparseexception-object-not-found-for-update-error-when-the-object-exists) Parse forum discussion 
   **ACL settings are the  default are public read, owner-write. You can change those to allow writes by other users**.

By using below code:-

```
ParseACL postACL = new ParseACL(ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
postACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
postACL.setPublicWriteAccess(true);
```